# Word break problem when Splitting string into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script called splt.js to split strings and animate the letters. The problem is that this script is splitting all letters and white spaces into spans and sometimes words break. What I would like to do is to modify the script so I could first split the string into words and then letters. Could someone help me with that? This is the code:

```
function splt({ target = '.splt', reveal = false }) {
  let saveOriginal = [];

  //grab instances
  const inst = document.querySelectorAll(target);

  for (let a = 0; a < inst.length; a++) {
    inst[a].setAttribute('id', 'i' + [a + 1]);

    //saves original text to an array for revert functionality
    saveOriginal.push(inst[a].innerHTML);

    //split instance text
    const instChars = inst[a].innerHTML.split('');
    for (let b = 0; b < instChars.length; b++) {
      //nest child span
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      inst[a].appendChild(span);
      span.setAttribute('id', 'c' + [b + 1]);

      //check if child = char or whitespace
      if (instChars[b] == ' ') {
        span.classList.add('whtSpc');
      } else {
        span.classList.add('char');
        //add char styles
        const char = document.querySelectorAll('.char');
        for (let c = 0; c < char.length; c++) {
          char[c].style.display = 'inline-block';
          char[c].style.overflow = 'hidden';
          char[c].style.verticalAlign = 'top';
        }
      }

      //reveal init
      if (reveal == true) {
        //nest grandchild span
        const spanChild = document.createElement('span');
        spanChild.innerHTML = instChars[b]; //set text to grandchild span
        span.appendChild(spanChild);
        spanChild.setAttribute('id', 'r');
        spanChild.classList.add('reveal');
        //add charReveal styles
        const charReveal = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');
        for (let d = 0; d < charReveal.length; d++) {
          charReveal[d].style.display = 'inherit';
          charReveal[d].style.overflow = 'inherit';
          charReveal[d].style.verticalAlign = 'inherit';
        }
      } else {
        span.innerHTML = instChars[b]; //set text to child span
      }
    }

    inst[a].removeChild(inst[a].childNodes[0]); // remove initial text input
  }

  //undo text splitting
  splt.revert = () => {
    for (let e = 0; e < inst.length; e++) {
      inst[e].removeAttribute('id');
      inst[e].innerHTML = saveOriginal[e]; //sets text to original value
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: `string into words and then letters.`,  could you explain that bit in more details, because splitting a string into words, and then letters, would end up splitting into letters..

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878) - what have you tried, where exactly did you run into problems?

Comment: Ok! Lets try again. The problem is that the words sometimes break and a letter end up on a new row. making a text look something like this: https://imgur.com/a/0KtqE9l

Comment: @freedomn-m do you normally add ids to your individual letters?

Comment: @freedomn-m but the idea of adding a parameter for words and letters is really good. But I can't call the function twice without errors. It first splits the words and in spans and after that the individual letters. I want to split the letters inside the split words. :)

Comment: @Keith the problem is that words break and letters end up on a different row. The reason I want to first group the words is so that I have a chance of keeping them together.

Comment: @CBroe what I've tried is the script from spltjs.com but it break words. The author thinks I should solve it by changing the font size (which works) but that is not really the most dynamic solution. So my idea is to modify the script to split the string by words before letters. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break strings into words by `split`ting them by spaces. Then create word `span`s with appropriate styling that don't break letter `span`s within themselves.

```js
function splt({ target = '.splt', reveal = false }) {
  let saveOriginal = [];
  //grab instances
  const inst = document.querySelectorAll(target);

  for (let a = 0; a < inst.length; a++) {
    inst[a].setAttribute('id', 'i' + [a + 1]);

    //saves original text to an array for revert functionality
    saveOriginal.push(inst[a].innerHTML);

        //split instance text into words
    const instWords = inst[a].innerHTML.split(' '); //split into words by spaces
    for (let i = 0; i < instWords.length; i++) {
        const word = document.createElement('span'); //word span
        //split instance text
        instWords[i] += " "; //add a space back since the delimeter is omitted
        const instChars = instWords[i].split('');
        for (let b = 0; b < instChars.length; b++) {
        //nest child span
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        word.appendChild(span);
        span.setAttribute('id', 'c' + [b + 1]);

        //check if child = char or whitespace
        if (instChars[b] == ' ') {
            span.classList.add('whtSpc');
        } else {
            span.classList.add('char');
        }

        //reveal init
        if (reveal == true) {
            //nest grandchild span
            const spanChild = document.createElement('span');
            spanChild.innerHTML = instChars[b]; //set text to grandchild span
            span.appendChild(spanChild);
            spanChild.setAttribute('id', 'r');
            spanChild.classList.add('reveal');
            //add charReveal styles
        } else {
            span.innerHTML = instChars[b]; //set text to child span
        }
        }
        word.style.display = 'inline-block'; //keep letter spans together; this trims space spans
        inst[a].appendChild(word);
        }
    inst[a].removeChild(inst[a].childNodes[0]); // remove initial text input
  }
  
  //move element styling outside loops so it's done only once
    const char = document.querySelectorAll('.char');
  for (let c = 0; c < char.length; c++) {
    char[c].style.display = 'inline-block';
    char[c].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    char[c].style.verticalAlign = 'top';
  }
        
  const whtSpc = document.querySelectorAll('.whtSpc');
  for (let s = 0; s < whtSpc.length; s++) {
    whtSpc[s].style["white-space"] = 'pre'; //make space spans visible from trimming
  }
        
  if (reveal == true) {
    const charReveal = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');
    for (let d = 0; d < charReveal.length; d++) {
        charReveal[d].style.display = 'inherit';
        charReveal[d].style.overflow = 'inherit';
        charReveal[d].style.verticalAlign = 'inherit';
    }
  }
  //undo text splitting
   splt.revert = () => {
    for (let e = 0; e < inst.length; e++) {
      inst[e].removeAttribute('id');
      inst[e].innerHTML = saveOriginal[e]; //sets text to original value
    }
  };
}

splt({ target:'.splt', reveal: false});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="splt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted it to! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just ran into a new problem with this. When using special characters like '&' this will display it like &amp;. Do you have any idea how I could solve that?